# Using GAP/GATT Services Bluetooth LE in Windows 10 without pairing first

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

We need to use GAP/GATT Services in a Windows 10 Universal App, Bluetooth LowEnergy, to write (just as example) some characteristic value to some Bluetooth LE Device.

Now, currently under Windows 10 nothing is possible without pairing manually first.

Unfortunately the devices that we want to handle do not accept pairing...we cannot change this behavior.

We already have iOS and Android Apps, they work because pairing is not required. We cannot develop a Windows 10 Universal App at the moment because of this limitation.

My question: does anyone know what Microsoft is going to do with this behavior?
Any new APIs coming to market?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I work on the Windows Bluetooth team and we are aware of this limitation. We are working to ship an API that is able to communicate w/ BLE devices without the need to explicitly pair. We already shipped the ability to talk to a Bluetooth classic device (and we are working to ship the BLE API later this year) - https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/P460

Comment: Hi Kiran, do you know when this feature will be available in Insider build ?

Comment: Hi Kiran, is this available now? Thank you

Comment: No, I will link back to a blog post once it's available.

Comment: Thank you for your effort Kiran. We are also waiting for this feature to become available!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry for my delay in answering you, at the moment we are working on the same app but Android and iOS. Probably later this year we shall be back on Windows, therefore this feature is really needed.

Comment: Check out the latest insider build (and SDK) - https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/13/new-bluetooth-features-in-creators-update-gatt-server-bluetooth-le/